# Internet Explorer 8 Keyboard Shortcut for Find Next

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-8

After I type CTRL-F in Internet Explorer 8 and type my query, how do I cycle through the results with the keyboard?

In Firefox, I would use CTRL-g. That doesn't work in IE8. It was also suggested to use F3, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you type what you are looking for, it will be highligted, then press Enter... it's as simple as that. You will scroll among all results.